# Scroll View and clearing widget in kivy

Tags: python, kivy, widget, scrollview, textinput

I'm new to Kivy and don't know everything yet. I've been struggling for days now to finish this little app that takes an xlsx file and uses it as a search base.

But my problem is that I don't know how to clear the results widget after pressing "Search" again and I am also trying to add scrolling for the search results. I simplified the program, but the principle remains the same. If you can tell me what I did wrong or how I should Google it.

```
   import kivy


    from kivy.app import App
    from kivy.uix.label import Label
    from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
    from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
    from kivy.uix.button import Button

    from kivy.app import runTouchApp

    class MyGrid(GridLayout):
        def __init__(self, **kwargs):
            super(MyGrid, self).__init__(**kwargs)

            self.cols = 1

            self.inside  = GridLayout()
            self.inside.cols = 2

            self.inside.add_widget(Label(text="Label Name: "))
            self.label_name = TextInput(multiline=False)
            self.inside.add_widget(self.label_name)

            self.add_widget(self.inside)

            self.search = Button(text="Search", font_size=30)
            self.search.bind(on_press=self.pressed)
            self.add_widget(self.search)

            self.print = GridLayout()
            self.print.cols = 1
        
            self.add_widget(self.print)

        
       

    #Here a problem:

        def pressed(self, result):
            self.print.clear_widgets()
            # file = load_xlsx(self.label_name.text)
            for info in range(10):
                btn = Button(text=str(info), size_hint_y=None, height=40)
                self.print.add_widget(btn)
            
    class MyApp(App):
        def build(self):
            return MyGrid()

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        MyApp().run()
```

Comment: Try using method [`clear_widgets`](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.widget.html#kivy.uix.widget.Widget.clear_widgets).

Answer (score 0):

The example below allows you to clear widgets when you click the search button again, it is best to implement similar logic using `RecycleView`, because it dynamically loads content, which will allow you to display an almost unlimited number of widgets on the screen. When you enter a number in `TextInput`, the program will add widgets to the screen if they contain a digit passed in the input field. Tip, use `.kv`, it's convenient, and there is also syntax highlighting, use [dp](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.metrics.html) for dimensions - this is an abstract unit of measurement based on the physical density of the screen, allows you to keep the size of widgets the same on all screens and platforms.

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.metrics import dp

KV = """
Screen:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        
        BoxLayout:
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.minimum_height
            
            Label:
                text: "Label Name: "
                
            TextInput:
                id: search_text
                multiline: False
                size_hint_y: None
                height: dp(50)
                
        Button:
            text: "Search"
            font_size: sp(30)
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5}
            size_hint_y: None
            height: dp(50)
            on_release: app.pressed(search_text.text)
                
        RecycleView:
            id: rv_result
            key_size: "height"
            bar_width: dp(4)
            always_overscroll: False
            key_viewclass: "viewclass"
    
            RecycleGridLayout:
                id: result
                default_size_hint: 1, None
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.minimum_height
                padding: dp(5)
                spacing: dp(7)
                cols: 1
                default_size: None, dp(48)
"""


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

    def pressed(self, result):
        if self.root.ids.rv_result.data:
            self.root.ids.rv_result.data = []
            self.root.ids.rv_result.refresh_from_layout()

        for info in range(100):
            info = str(info)

            if result in info:
                item = {
                    'viewclass': 'Button',
                    'text': info,
                    'size_hint_y': None,
                    'height': dp(40),
                }

                self.root.ids.rv_result.data.append(item)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

[image]
[image]